# rewrite rule for dynamic subfolders using .htaccess in the root directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have this dynamically generated url: `/folder/folder/folder/folder/index.php?product=bike`

Which i need to convert to a static url: `/folder/folder/folder/folder/product/bike`

.htaccess is in the root folder

code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=1$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  index.php?product=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need `../index.php?product=bike` to be rewritten as `../product/bike/`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)product=(.*)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.php$  $1/product/%1? [NC,L]
```

Comment: no i need the other way /folder/folder/folder/folder/index.php?product=bike to be written as /folder/folder/folder/folder/product/bike